# Universal keybindings in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, key-bindings

I want to be able to use CTRL-SHIFT-T to open a Java Type  (source code file) from *any perspective* in Eclipse. Unfortunately, the keybinding  only works in the Java perspective.

I tried defining the keybindings using context "In Windows" and "In Dialogs and Windows."  That did not do the trick.

Any ideas how to do this?

(For documentation, note e.g. [this page](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/accessibility/keyboardshortcuts.htm).)

[Image Hosted by ImageShack.us http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7205/keybindingsna4.png](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/7205/keybindingsna4.png)
Shot at 2009-02-18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the command 'Java Navigate' in the perspective from which you want to access the "Open Type" dialog.

[image]

You will access this dialog through a right click "Customize Perspective" near the toolbbar buttons.

As mentioned in [lud0h's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560452#560725), "you have to do this in all perspectives you normally use to get this functionality across all of them"

Until... [eclipse3.5M4 late this January 200099](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/12/whats-cooking-in-m4.html)

> Java Action sets in all perspectives:
>
> If you are editing a Java file, you can access your favourite actions (Open Type etc) in a non-java perspective as well (CVS, Resource)

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse go to:

1. Window -> Customize Perspective...
2. Click on "Commands" tab
3. Select the check box for "Java Navigation"
4. Click "ok"

Now you can use Ctrl + Shift + T in this perspective.

Unfortunately you have to do this in all perspectives you normally use to get this functionality across all of them.

Comment: Good description, 30 seconds faster than me ;) +1